# Compiler command and GCC version

Tags: c++, gcc, c++11, g++, command

I'm taking part in a programming contest and the requirement is that code will be compiled using following command: 
**g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -o a.out orienteering.cpp**
How do I check if my code works for this command? (I use DevC++ for coding and it has automatic compilation). 
Also compiler should be GCC 4.8.2 or later. What does this mean? Is my older GCC version (4.7.2) not suitable?

Comment: gcc 4.7.2 probably doesn't have as much support for C++11 as gcc 4.8.2.

Comment: See here https://gcc.gnu.org/projects/cxx0x.html the various C++11 features per gcc version. That command is a basic compile command with `-O2` optimisation switch, set in the `compiler options` tab. You may want to consider using a more up-to-date (supported) IDE http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dev-C%2B%2B, such as Code::Blocks http://www.codeblocks.org/

Comment: The answers to this seem self-evident...?

Answer (score 0):

You check your code by placing it in a file named `orienteering.cpp`, and running this command in the same directory:

```
g++ -std=c++11 -O2 -o a.out orienteering.cpp
```

If the compiler spits out any messages at all then you have a problem. If the compiler is silent and creates a file named `a.out`, then all is well.

GCC 4.7.2 does not meet the criteria "GCC 4.8.2 or later".